# How do I find specific buildings in Tropico 4?

Tags: tropico-4

How can I find specific building on the map? For example I need to find all clinics. Is there better way than clicking on each doctor and looking up where he works?

Comment: The closest I can come up with is showing the 'services' overlay, but then there are so many buildings under that category that its still hard to find a clinic.  I'm not sure if its possible to show only a specific type of building.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select a building of a specific type but to find clinics you could go to the jobs section of the almanac and find a doctors location, he/she should usually be close to the clinic they work in. Other than that there isnt a way of highlighting clinics

Answer (score 0):

there ought to be a button in the overlay section that you can use to show health quality among all tropicans and highlight all of the health-related buildings